# Does html specification state what happens when both bottom and margin-bottom are specified?

Tags: html, css

To me specifying both `bottom` and `margin-bottom` seems like a contradiction. Because both are means to specify indent between the element and surrounding elements/containers. That is, `bottom` should be measured from the border, otherwise it's indent measured from indent. Does anyone know what the specification has to say?

Comment: It's the CSS spec, since we're talking about CSS, but it does have [an entire subsection dedicated to answering this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins). Also see [the preceding section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bottom` property "specifies how far a box's bottom margin edge is offset above the bottom of the box's containing block"<sup>[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props)</sup>. And

> The margin edge surrounds the box margin. If the margin has 0 width, the margin edge is the same as the border edge. The four margin edges define the box's margin box."<sup>[2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-edge)</sup>

So yes, specification says that `bottom` is measured from margin edge.